# C# VSTO 2015 - dll is not a valid Office Add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-office, vsto, powerpoint

I have just created a new `PowerPoint web add-in project` and developed a simple web based application. Then I build the solution and the `.dll` file is **successfully** created. When I open **PowerPoint 2016**, I could not see my add-in in the `My Add-ins` list. When I try to point the `dll` file of my web add-in manually, getting this error: `x.dll is not a valid Office Add-in`

How can I integrate my web add-in into PowerPoint in order to use it with slides?

Comment: 'web add-in' and 'web-based application' does not sound like a VSTO add-in.

Comment: @CharlesMager I aim that: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/office

Comment: And if you read down to the bit about installing add-ins, you'll see how to install them in the Office 365 web app. These add ins aren't VSTO add-ins and can't be used in the desktop apps. There would be no dll either, so your question still sounds muddled.